# Confusion about the axis in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

there is currently two arguments here, one based on data frames are just vertical pandas series with same index.hence the picture below

```
df.max(axis=1) # max applied horizontally
```

[image]

and it seems work with aggregate functions.

but when I work with

`pd.drop(axis=1)`

it actually drops the columns (vertically) shown by the picture.
both seem true, how to solve the contradiction then.

Comment: It's not you, it's `Pandas` :-).

Comment: I like to think of it as moving along the specified axis and doing a certain action. if you are using max (axis=1), then you moving along axis 1 and trying to find the max in that direction. If you are using drop, then you are moving along the axis1 and droping column or columns ( or if you moving along axis 0, then dropping rows). If this is hard to remember, use "Columns" option instead of axis in drop (no need to use axis=1 option).